# Django 2.0 Upgrade - False Positives on urls.W001 Warning

Tags: python, django

I'm upgrading a Django project from Django 1.11 to Django 2.1.7, and after changing all the URL patterns to the Django 2 way of doing things, I'm getting a bunch of false positives on the urls.W001 warning when I do manage.py runserver.

Example:

`?: (urls.W001) Your URL pattern '^some-pattern/$' [name='some_name'] uses include with a route ending with a '$'. Remove the dollar from the route to avoid problems including URLs.`

When I look at that URL pattern in my urls.py file, however, it absolutely doesn't have a ^ or $ in it.

`path('some-pattern/', views.some_view_function, name='some_name'),`

I've blown away both my local virtualenv and my Vagrant box and started from scratch just to make sure it's not some lingering compiled stuff somewhere, but the behavior is the same when starting from scratch.

Has anyone else run into this? The app itself seems to run fine, I'm just flummoxed at where Django might be seeing things that don't exist anywhere in my code.

Thanks for any ideas anyone might have.

Comment: are you sure the urls.py file containing the url pattern `some_name` isn't included in a higher level urls.py where you're still using the "$"? e.g. `some_name` is a url pattern in `blog.urls` and in `my_app.urls` you have `include(blog.urls)`

Comment: By starting from scratch - did you recreate whole project from new? If not, there might be some `.pyc` files or `__pycache__` worth removing; on ubuntu you may be able to use `pyclean` tool for it.

Comment: I'd search the entire project for the pattern, just in case, with something like this: `fgrep --include=*.py -ri "^some-pattern/$" .` See if it is lurking about somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for all the great suggestions -- definitely have searched the codebase as well as the entire directory structure for the virtualenv and literally blown everything away when restarting, but always good to double-check. We're starting to think this may have something to do with Django CMS and how it handles apphook urls internally since we can't yet determine another explanation. Thanks for the ideas! If/when we get to a resolution I'll be sure and update here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this was indeed related to Django CMS -- this is the first release of theirs that supports Django 2 but it still supports Django 1.11 also, so they're shooting down the middle in some spots and when it pulls in URLs for our apphooks they get translated into patterns with ^ and $ in the mix. Hope that info helps someone else who may run into this. Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: For the moment, waiting for a solution in next versions of Django CMS I've silenced the warning in settings.py with SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ['urls.W001']

Answer (score 1):

it happened to me when i had two django projects running on my pc , the thing is that if you don't use a virtual enviroment things get messy and it always go to the same list of paths.

I would first change names of directions you're trying to access just so you know if it's going there to checke the list of routes

next be carefull because with the routes of path
path('this-way/...  it's different from path('/this-way/'... 
path('this-way/... adds '/this-way/' to the direction of the browser
example: https://localhost:8000/login changes to https://localhost:8000/login/this-way/
that's where the $ might come from

Answer (score 1):

As @matt says the culprit is Django CMS transition to Django 2.0.

I've silenced the warnings with

```
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ['urls.W001']
```

in settings.py